# Microsoft Sync Framework or alternative for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm developing an application for Windows 8 (WinRT) which performing synchronization of two folders. While searching information on best ways to compare and synchronize all files (which can be a lot), I came across Microsoft Sync Framework and its File Synchronization Provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623.aspx

I tried it in classic desktop way and found out that it's pretty useful framework, with lots of tasty options. But guess what - does not support WinRT applications. Well, that's understandable, considering all restrictions of the platform in terms of interaction with the file system.

Is there any alternative of it for WinRT applications? Or any tools that can make my task easier, for that matter? All that I could found in Internet is about database synchronization or so, I don't need that right now.

Comment: I'm searching for more or less the same. Do you have found a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a third-party Windows RT variant of the Synchronization Framework available on CodePlex, if you still need it:

http://syncwinrt.codeplex.com/